# Remove Repeated Code

Tags: java

My Question is-

I have two string variables `site_inclusion` and `site_exclusion`.  If `site_inclusion` has a value, then I don't care what values `site_exclusion` contains.  That is to say that `site_inclusion` overrides `site_exclusion`.  If, however,  `site_inclusion` is `null` and `site_exclusion` has a value, then I want to examine `site_exclusion`.

To be more precise:

1. If `site_inclusion` and `site_exclusion` are both `null` then set `useTheSynthesizer` as `true`;
2. If `site_inclusion` is not `null` and it matches with the `regexPattern` then set `useTheSynthesizer` as `true`.  And I don't care what values are there in `site_exclusion`.
3. If `site_inclusion` is `null` and `site_exclusion` is not `null` and `site_exclusion` does not match the `regexPattern` then set `useTheSynthesizer` to true.

I wrote the below code but somehow I think, **I am repeating some stuff here** in the if/else loop. Any code improvements will be appreciated that fulfill my conditions.

```
String site_inclusion = metadata.getSiteInclusion();
String site_exclusion = metadata.getSiteExclusion();

// fix for redundant data per site issue
if(site_inclusion != null && site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern)) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
} else if(site_exclusion != null && !(site_exclusion.matches(regexPattern))) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
} else if(site_inclusion == null && site_exclusion == null ) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
}
```

Comment: Probably better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Torious: indeed.  I didn't even notice the codereview SE.

Comment: Your sample code does not match your description.  If `site_inclusion` is NOT null and it does NOT match the pattern, your sample code proceeds to check `site_exclusion` for a match.  This contradicts point #2, where you say you do NOT care about `site_exclusion` if `site_inclusion` is NOT null.

Comment: Yes my code has some problem, that is the reason I wanted to make sure my code can be improved or if there is any problem with that.

Comment: In this case improving your code and achieving the goal of your code are two different tasks.  The moral of the story: boolean logic can easily become quite tricky!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You don't really need the last `null` test.
2. I (personally) find it poor style to do an `if(test == true) flag = true` statement.  You can simply say `flag = test`.

My recommendation would be:

```
if(site_inclusion != null)
{
    useTheSynthesizer = site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern);
}
else if(site_exclusion != null)
{
    useTheSynthesizer = ! site_exclusion.matches(regexPattern);
}
else
{
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
}
```

You could also do it in a oneliner:

```
useTheSynthesizer = site_inclusion != null ? site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern) : (site_exclusion != null ? ! site_exclusion.matches(regexPattern) : true);
```

But I find that sort of obnoxious to read.

(Note, I made the assumption that `useTheSynthesizer` was otherwise `false`.  This isn't explicit in your code or explanation, but I think this assumption was safe.)

Comment: Thanks Edward, Today I learned few more things. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  If `site_inclusion` is not null, but doesn't match the pattern, then `site_exclusion` should be processed.  This answer assumes that `useTheSynthesizer` should always return false whenever `site_inclusion` is non-null and does not match.

Comment: If site_inclusion has some values then site_inclusion will override anything in site_exclusion, basically I will not bother what site_exclusion has. But if site_inclusion is null and site_exclusion has something, then in that case I will examing site_exclusion.

Comment: @jahroy: hmm, yes, the way I read bullet point number 3 would indicate that a non-null, non-matching `site_inclusion` is ignored, but the sample code suggests otherwise.

Comment: @EdwardThomson - Maybe the OP's original sample code is where the mistake exists.  I attempted to simplify his sample code without changing the logic in my answer.  Now I'm not sure which is correct: the OP's description or his sample code!

Comment: @user1419563: do note that the code above is not an accurate translation of your example code.  as @jahroy notes, when `site_inclusion` is non-null and does NOT match the regular expression, `site_exclusion` is still evaluated in your code whereas in the above, it is not evaluated.

Comment: @Edward, that's what I want that you did in your code. It's matches with my requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
    boolean useTheSynthesizer;

    if (siteInclusion == null && siteExclusion == null) {
        useTheSynthesizer = true;
    }
    else if (siteInclusion == null) {
        useTheSynthesizer = ( ! siteExclusion.matches(regexPattern) );
    }
    else {
        useTheSynthesizer = siteInclusion.matches(regexPattern);
    }
```

I also removed the underscores from your variable names, since they do not fit the java naming conventions (and they're hideous IMO).

Comment: Note that the above is a simplification of the OP's sample code.  It does NOT, however, match the description of the requirements (from bullet points).  The sample code and problem description are contradictory.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. Basically i extracted all the conditions as small methods and made as OR condition.

```
    String site_inclusion = metadata.getSiteInclusion();
    String site_exclusion = metadata.getSiteExclusion();
        if(isInclusionAndExclusionNull(site_inclusion, site_exclusion) || isSiteExclusionMatches(site_exclusion, regexPattern) || isSiteInclusionMatches(site_inclusion, regexPattern)) {
            useTheSynthesizer = true;
        }

private static boolean isInclusionAndExclusionNull(String site_inclusion,
            String site_exclusion) {
        return site_inclusion == null && site_exclusion == null;
    }    
    private boolean isSiteExclusionMatches(String site_exclusion,
                String regexPattern) {
            return site_exclusion != null && !(site_exclusion.matches(regexPattern));
        }

        private  boolean isSiteInclusionMatches(String site_inclusion,
                String regexPattern) {
            return site_inclusion != null && site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 methods for flexibility to process the inclusions and exclusions like below..

```
callingMethod() {
  boolean useTheSynthesizer = processSiteInclusions(site_inclusion, regexPattern);

  if (useTheSynthesizer == false) {
     useTheSynthesizer = processSiteExclusions(site_inclusion, regexPattern);
  }

  if (useTheSynthesizer == false) {
    useTheSynthesizer = true;
  }
}

private boolean processSiteInclusions(site_inclusion, regexPattern) {
   boolean useSynthesizer = false;

   if (site_inclusion != null && !site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern))
      useSynthesizer = true;

   return useSynthesizer;
}

private boolean processSiteExclusions(site_exclusion, regexPattern) {
   boolean useSynthesizer = false;

   if (site_exclusion != null && !site_inclusion.matches(regexPattern))
      useSynthesizer = true;

   return useSynthesizer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I think you can improve it using some like OR, and no only AND or try somethin like swicht case.

Anyways you can create some function that tested your variables, and you can write this confusing code out from your main module.

For example you can write this code in a function called `boolean TestingVariable ( String X,  String Y);`

For example:
    boolean TesteingVariable ( String X,  String Y){

```
  if(X != null && X.matches(regexPattern)) {
      return true;
  } else if(Y != null && !(Y.matches(regexPattern))) {
      return = true;
  } else if(X == null && Y == null ) {
      return = true;
  }
};
```

On this way your final main module code will be something like this and you will avoid the confused code in your main code:

```
String site_inclusion = metadata.getSiteInclusion();
String site_exclusion = metadata.getSiteExclusion();

// fix for redundant data per site issue
useTheSynthesizer = TesteingVariable (site_inclusion ,site_exclusion);
```

I think you should enter the variable `regexPattern` in the function.

Sorry for my English I hope you can undertand all and it help to you.